# How do you redirect in ColdFusion and control the status code (i.e. 301 instead of a 302)

Tags: redirect, coldfusion, http-status-code-301

This code does a redirect, but uses a 302 status code:

```
<cflocation url="http://stackoverflow.com" addToken="no" />
```

I found this on the Internet, but I think it only works in ColdFusion8.  I am using ColdFusion7.

```
<cflocation url="http://stackoverflow.com" addToken="no" statuscode="301" />
```

Hoe do you control the status code in ColdFusion7?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<cfheader statuscode="301" statustext="Moved permanently">
<cfheader name="Location" value="http://stackoverflow.com">`

Comment: And, of course, if you want a different status code, change the statustext accordingly.