# 301 Redirect In ColdFusion

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, coldfusion, url-rewriting

I need to redirect my site from http://panelteccorp.com/store/index.cfm/category/2/applications.cfm
 to http://panelteccorp.com/applications.html, and some more pages like this. In this application, application.cfm is my default page.  When I am trying 301 redirect, all pages are getting redirected to the home page.  The whole website is in ColdFusion. Please give some advice on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you redirect in ColdFusion and control the status code (i.e. 301 instead of a 302)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503300/how-do-you-redirect-in-coldfusion-and-control-the-status-code-i-e-301-instead)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want that specific ColdFusion page to redirect then all you need to do is add this line of code at the top.

```
<cflocation url='/applications.html' statuscode='301' addtoken='false' />
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is not 301 redirect this is known as url rewriting

you can try this code in your .htaccess file

---

RewriteEngine on

### RewriteRule ^applications.html$ /store/index.cfm/category/2/applications.cfm [L]

This will redirect your page to the required one.This way you can do for all

Hope you know about regex...:P

Comment: RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
...RewriteRule ^store/index\.cfm/category/2/applications\.cfm$ /applications.html? [R=301,NE,NC,L]

be sure mod_rewrite is enabled on your server

Comment: If you check out his site listed, it sends back.. Server:Microsoft-IIS/6.0 so the Apache method won't work. :p